# Summation of a complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

Is there a way to perform the finite sum
$\sum_{m = 1}^n \exp(2 \pi i k (\sqrt5) ^m)$?, m even.

I am trying to show a specific sequence is not equidistributed, and so I'd like to show that Weyl's criterion fails, but I am not sure how to perform this sum, since it is not a geometric series.

Comment: Currently your index does not appear in your summand. Did you mean to write $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\exp\left(2\pi i k(\sqrt{5})^n\right)$$ rather than $$\sum_{m=1}^{n}\exp\left(2\pi i k(\sqrt{5})^n\right)$$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: I am confused. Are you trying to evaluate
$$\sum_{m=1}^{n}\exp(2\pi i k(\sqrt{5})^m)$$ or $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\exp(2\pi i k(\sqrt{5})^n)$$. You just stated it was the latter that you meant, yet your edit provides the former as the series you intend.

Also, if $m$ must be even, your series cannot begin at $1$.

Comment: Right, ack. I've edited the post.  It's the first thing you typed,and m should start at 2.

Comment: Maybe you could just tell us what sequence is the one whose distribution you are investigating?

Answer (score 2):

As written, the sum is $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$ since $\exp(2\pi ik5^{m/2})=1$ for $m$ even.

Comment: Oh. Duh. ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

An elaboration on what has been stated:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=2, m \text{ even}}^{n}\exp\left(2\pi i k \left(\sqrt{5}\right)^m\right)&=\sum_{m=2, m \text{ even}}^{n}e^{2\pi ik \cdot 5^{\frac{m}{2}}}\\
&=\sum_{m=2,m \text{ even}}^{n}\left(e^{2\pi i}\right)^{k\cdot 5^{\frac{m}{2}}}\\
e^{2\pi i}&=1\\
\therefore \sum_{m=2,m \text{ even}}^{n}\left(e^{2\pi i}\right)^{k\cdot 5^{\frac{m}{2}}}&=\sum_{m=2, m \text{ even}}^{n}1^{k\cdot 5^{\frac{m}{2}}}\\
&=\underbrace{1+1+1+\dots}_{\frac{n}{2} \text{ ones}}\\
&=\left \{ \begin{array}{cl}
\frac{n}{2}&n \text{ even }\\
\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor &n \text{ odd}
\end{array} \right.
\end{align}
$$